# How can I extract parts of a mixed list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
lst = {
    {1, {{"abc", "bcd"}, {"cd", "efg", "fghi"}, {"g"}}},
    {2, {{"abcd"}, {"bc", "cdef"}, {"defgh"}}}
};
```

**By using `Parts`**, I would like to extract the following list:

```
res = {{1, {{"abc", "bcd"}}}, {2, {{"abcd"}}}};
```

I know that I can do it quite easily with

```
res = Map[{#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}} &, lst];
```

but it is annoying me that I cannot seem to do it using `Parts`.  I tried

```
res = lst[[All, {1, {2, 1}}]];
res = lst[[All, 1, {2, 1}]];
```

and numerous other variations, but none of them worked.

Comment: I am afraid you are tilting at windmills. For a simple list you can use a list to extract elements. However, for a multi-dimensional list this ability is not available.

Comment: @JackLaVigne thanks for the notice.  I'm afraid that you are right.  **Moderators**, please feel free to close the question if appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because `Part` can not do what the question asks of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can come close with the command `Extract`, which is closely related to `Part`.

```
Extract[lst, #] & /@ {{{1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}}

{{1, {"abc", "bcd"}}, {2, {"abcd"}}}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. The 2nd element of each element should be wrapped in `List`; e.g., `{"abcd"}` should be `{{"abcd"}}`.

Comment: Using `Extract` also isn't what he asked for... this is as close as i could come.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think it's close enough to be a good answer.